# CFDictionaryCreate analogue of [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject ... ]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-foundation

I'm looking the way to create following dictionary

```
    NSDictionary *frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary 
                                                  dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] 
                                                                forKey:(NSString *) kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]
                                     forKey:(NSString *) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
```

By means of CoreFoundation i.e. with `CFDictionaryCreate`

Any Ideas how to implement this ?

Comment: Can't you just cast the NSDictionary to a CFDictionary?

Comment: Of course NOT, hah, then whats the idea of my question ?! I'm coding in pure C++/C...

Comment: Given that the core of CF is entirely implemented in Objective-C using the NS* classes, why can't you cast exactly?

Comment: @bbum: Wha-ha? CF is implemented using Cocoa classes?! I thought it was the other way around?

Comment: Lots of people think that and, at one time, it was largely true.  But not any more!  "Entirely" is too strong of a word;  lots of it is in ObjC, lots in C.  Moving more and more to ObjC over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems I've constructed the answer on my own, please confirm someone. The code compiles OK, but I'm not able to test it yet.

```
    int delayOnEachFrame = 2;
    const void *tkeys[1] = { kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime };
    const void *tvalues[1] = { CFNumberCreate(0, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &delayOnEachFrame) };
    CFDictionaryRef tframeProperties = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, tkeys, tvalues, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    const void *keys[1] = { kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary };
    const void *values[1] = { tframeProperties };
    CFDictionaryRef frameProperties = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

Comment: That's basically correct, although don't forget memory management. You need to release the `CFNumber` in `tvalues`, `tframeProperties`, and eventually `frameProperties`. Also, if you have just one key-value pair, you don't need to create actual arrays. You can just create lone variables and pass the pointers to them.

Comment: Hey, do you know the swift equivalent for this?